# .htacces redirecting from http to https issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

I have this .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I want to modify `.htaccess`, that site always show `https` in url. I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this don't work. I tried also

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

but in this case I got `This webpage has a redirect loop` error..
Help me to configure that please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason why this code not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

this is what the certificate give you `cloudflare` or something other similar service, when you hasn't direct control to your ssl certificate.
I had such problem with ssl from cloudflare, and I solve that with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [L]
```